# WordPress Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "nodeType" on cross-origin object

Tags: php, wordpress

I’m facing a strange error in the console log while updating quantity of product from the cart or checkout page. I’m getting this message in the error log:

> Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property “nodeType”
> on cross-origin object

and the cart stucks on loading state. When I refresh with F5 I can clearly see the cart being updated with the right quantity. My debugging shows that the problem comes from a conflict between my custom plugin which is using the `woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping` hook:

```
function wm_woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_hook_callback( $needs_shipping ){

    WC()->session = new WC_Session_Handler();
    WC()->session->init();

    if(WC()->session->get( 'wm_store_method' ) && WC()->session->get( 'wm_store_method' ) == "vault") {
        $needs_shipping = false;
        return $needs_shipping;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

and the **WooCommerce Stripe Payment Gateway** plugin. I know that my custom plugin's code is causing the problem because when I remove this function's contents the problem disappears. Any idea what might cause this error and how to fix it? My custom plugin depends hardly on this `woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping` hook and I cannot avoid this code in my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Тo avoid this conflict, I modified my code to only initialize the session handler once, rather than every time the `wm_woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_hook_callback` function is called.

```
function wm_woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_hook_callback( $needs_shipping ){

    // Check if the session handler has already been initialized
    if ( ! WC()->session ) {
        WC()->session = new WC_Session_Handler();
        WC()->session->init();
    }

    if(WC()->session->get( 'wm_store_method' ) && WC()->session->get( 'wm_store_method' ) == "vault") {
        $needs_shipping = false;
        return $needs_shipping;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

And this fixed the problem!